# Can you defeat Fallout 4 without siding with anyone?

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to defeat Fallout 4 without ever having sided with anyone?

There are certain story points which seem to indicate you'd need to be sided for this person or another to science their way into the institute, or whatever else NPCs need to do to further the story. But for all I know you can do it without siding.

Comment: Maybe at least this one is intresting for you: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289553/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

To science your way into the Institute, you need to have someone help you

> create the molecular relay. This can be either the Brotherhood, the Railroad, or the Minutemen.

This step requires you to side with a major faction, but your allegiance can still be changed.

To finish the main story line,

> you need to either side with the Institute and destroy the hostile factions, or side with one of the other three factions to destroy the Institute.

There is no other way to end the faction war. You could continue playing the game as long as you like without doing this, but you would never "finish" it.

Once you do finish it with one of the factions, the game is permanently changed, and the faction war ends.

More information can be found in the answers to [Is there a point of no return in Fallout 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243493/108003).

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. I beat it the standard way, then my 5 year old wanted to roam with a new character. She's managed to get up to level 46 without ever having talked to anyone beyond trading. She can read but I think the general fallout dialogue is beyond her comprehension so I didn't know how she would decide to join anything. The game is a lot less irritating when you don't get a volcano of distress quests from preston every 5 minutes and seeing how a 5 year old plays is very interesting.

Comment: @KaiQing Out of curiosity, what difficulty is your child playing on? I would think playing on a higher setting would require too much math and synergistic thinking for such a young child, but maybe not.

Comment: Very Hard. The game is ridiculously easy on other settings. She's learned to stalk slowly and use the sniper rifle as much as possible. It's amazing how much of this game she understands, much of which I didn't teach her. She assured me she knew how to pick locks. I didn't believe her, but she showed me. I did have to explain to her how things like vats work, how to decide what to eat, how to level up, etc. but mostly it's hands off. I work from home so fallout became a babysitter of sorts.