# Why does the Railroad want to destroy this faction?

Tags: fallout-4

**Spoiler question, do not read if you didn't complete the game at least once!**

After reading [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/289561/65045) to another question, I was intrigued by one of the spoilers:

> The Railroad will want you to destroy the Minutemen

While I understand that they want to put down the BoS, I was thinking they would want to destroy the Institute to liberate the synth.

In my first playthrough, I got so far I destroyed the BoS for them, but switched to the Institute at that moment, and destroyed thm before I could see that quest.

All along, the Railroad never have qualms about the Minutemen, and the Minutemen are quite neutral, so I don't understand why the Railroad is the only faction to want to put them down.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is flawed because according to the article it sources, there is no Minutemen destroying.

In fact, within the entirety of the vanilla Fallout 4 you cannot destroy the Minutemen Faction.  The only factions you can destroy are the Brotherhood of Steel, the Institute, and/or the Railroad.

Comment: So it was indeed the Institute that they wanted to destroy. Thanks