# What quests do you need to stop at before you make an enemy of a faction for each faction?

Tags: fallout-4

When completing faction/main quests in Fallout 4, you can eventually get to a point where you make a permanent enemy of a particular faction by completing a particular quest for another faction.  I'd like to create a saved game where I am at the point where whatever quest I do, I will make an enemy of a faction regardless.  The purpose of this is in order to check out all the game endings without having to restart the entire game again.

The question is, which quests for which factions are my stopping points and are there any things I need to be aware of to get to that nexus point?  I understand I can't make an enemy of the Minutemen but I can with all the other main factions.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

- ## Mass Fusion (/ Spoils of War)

  **Institute vs. Brotherhood of Steel**

  > Upon entering the relay, one should get a warning that **relaying to the
  >   Mass Fusion building will make them a permanent enemy to the
  >   Brotherhood of Steel**. Continue and the player character will be
  >   teleported to the Mass Fusion executive suite.
  >
  > Alternatively, by informing the Brotherhood, Spoils of War will start,
  >   and **boarding the Vertibird that spawns on the Prydwen will make the
  >   Institute hostile**.
  >   <sup>[source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Fusion)</sup>

  Once this mission has started, make your (first) save (see image below)!
- ## End of the Line

  **Institute vs. Railroad**

  The player can choose to either warn or kill Desdemona.
  <sup>[source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/End_of_the_Line)</sup>
- ## Blind Betrayal

  **Brotherhood of Steel vs. Railroad**

  As mentioned on the page for the quest *Tactical Thinking*:

  > If the player is not ready to close off activities with the Railroad,
  >   avoid turning in [Blind Betrayal] for now.
  >   <sup>[source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Tactical_Thinking)</sup>
- ### The Battle of Bunker Hill

  **Institute vs. Railroad**

  > Wrong dialogue choices [in the conversation the player has with Father during the mission debriefing], such as admitting it was the player
  >   character's fault, can lead to being banished from the Institute.
  >   <sup>[source](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_Battle_of_Bunker_Hill)</sup>

---

The infographic below shows how to get as many trophies/achievements in one walkthrough, and thus notes the points at which to make a save game:

[image: Fallout 4 main questline overview in regards to the separate factions]
 <sup>source unknown</sup>

Comment: Wow!  That exceeded my expectations.  Thank you and great job! :)

Comment: Yes, this answer is great!  Definitely Favoriting this one for reference later.  Thanks!

Comment: This is great.  I am doing another play through and will go with the Railroad this time.  Having the Institute is better for fast travel though.